# A question on linear independence and dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been trying to solve the second half of the following problem but so far I have not succeeded so far:

> Let $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$ be $n$ elements in a vector space
>   $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$. If they are linearly dependent and if any $n-1$
>   vectors among them are linearly dependent then there exists
>   $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{F}$ , none of which is $0$, such that
>   $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\alpha_{i}=0$. If $d_1,\ldots,d_{n}\in\mathbb{F}$
>   satisfy the same requirements then there is a $k\ne 0\in\mathbb{F}$
>   such that $d_{i}=kc_{i}, 1\le i\le n$.

Here's my attempt:

If $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$ are linearly dependent then there are $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{F}$, not all zero, such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}\alpha_{i} =0$$
If some $c_j=0$ we can assume after rearranging the indices that $c_1=0$ thus
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} c_{i}\alpha_{i} =0$$
Since any $n-1$ vectors are independent we must have $c_1=c_2=\ldots c_{n}=0$.
Thus $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$ are linearly independent which is a contradiction thus all of $c_i$'s are nonzero. This completes the first half of the proof.

Suppose that there are some $d_{1},\ldots,d_{n} \in\mathbb{F}$ where none of which are zero such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}\alpha_{i}=0$$

Then we can write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}\alpha_{i}=0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\alpha_{i}$$
that is
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(d_{i}-c_{i})\alpha_{i}=0$.

I'm not sure what can follow from here; How do I bring out the existence of such a $k$? **Hints would be appreciated.**

**UPDATE**: Suppose that there are some $d_{1},\ldots,d_{n} \in\mathbb{F}$ where none of which are zero such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}\alpha_{i}=0$$

Since $d_1 \ne 0$ we can write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}d_{1}^{-1}\alpha_{i}=0$$

And thus like previously,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(d_{i}d_{1}^{-1}-c_{i}c_{1}^{-1})\alpha_{i}=0$$
i.e.
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}(d_{i}d_{1}^{-1}-c_{i}c_{1}^{-1})\alpha_{i}=0$$
Since any $(n-1)$ vectors are independent, we have that $d_{i}=\frac{d_1}{c_1} c_{i}$ for all $2\le i\le n$. This completes the second part.

Comment: Indirect hint: you are given that $c_j, d_j$'s are all nonzero. Then could you do something to reduce the "degree of freedom"? Also note that we are working on a **field**.

Comment: @xbh hey I am not sure if I follow you; can you break it down even more?

Comment: Okay, my apologies. Directly, I claim that we could assume $c_1 = 1$, is it correct? If it is,  then the unknown coefficients are only $c_2$ thru $c_n$, i.e. we reduce "# of free variables" from $n$ to $n-1$, then we might be easier to proceed.

Comment: @xbh thanks for the hint! I completed the proof. Can you please check it?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much of it. Well done!